# FAT16 librarys on LPC2148 embedded. Can't update cluster position (Tricky!)

Tags: c++, pointers, append, sd-card, fat32

My code is using the Roland Riegel free library for FAT16,

The append function can find the file position or position in (Cluster 1) and save the new data to the correct position in the cluster. After countless file open and closes;

After the data overflows in the file from (Cluster 1) into (Cluster 2) the new data coming in is written perfectly fine.  However after the file is closed and reopened, only the file position is being updated and not the cluster.

So new data is being saved into the position in (Cluster 1) and in the correct position, BUT!!  It should be in (Cluster 2).

Been searching for a while now though I'd ask the experts.  Here's What I got!!

Sorry for the massive chain but its hard to see it otherwise....

```
string_printf(name, "MainLog.txt");
if(!root_file_exists(name)){
  handle = root_open_new(name);
}
else{
handle = root_open_append(name);
}


struct fat16_file_struct * root_open_append(char* name)
{
return(open_file_in_dir_append(fs,dd,name));
}
```

//////////////////////////////////// Append Structure //////////////////////////////////////

```
struct fat16_file_struct* open_file_in_dir_append(struct fat16_fs_struct* fs, struct fat16_dir_struct* dd, const char* name)
{

struct fat16_file_struct* result;
struct fat16_dir_entry_struct file_entry;

if(!find_file_in_dir(fs, dd, name, &file_entry))
    return 0;

     result = fat16_open_file(fs, &file_entry);
result->pos = result->dir_entry.file_size;


result->dir_entry.cluster = result->pos_cluster; // <<-Help here


return result;
}
```

//////////////////////////////// fat16_open_file Structure ///////////////////////////////

```
struct fat16_file_struct* fat16_open_file(struct fat16_fs_struct* fs, const struct fat16_dir_entry_struct* dir_entry)
{
rprintf("\nF16OpenFile\n\n");
if(!fs || !dir_entry || (dir_entry->attributes & FAT16_ATTRIB_DIR))
    return 0;

struct fat16_file_struct* fd = malloc(sizeof(*fd));
if(!fd)
    return 0;

memcpy(&fd->dir_entry, dir_entry, sizeof(*dir_entry));
fd->fs = fs;
fd->pos = 0;
fd->pos_cluster = dir_entry->cluster;
return fd;
}
```

///////////////////////////// Write Command ///////////////////

Called this way...

```
if(fat16_write_file(handle,(unsigned char *)RX_array1, stringSize) < 0)
{           
sd_raw_sync();
}
```

Actualy Structure here///

```
int16_t fat16_write_file(struct fat16_file_struct* fd, const uint8_t* buffer, uint16_t buffer_len)
{
#if FAT16_WRITE_SUPPORT
    /* check arguments */
    if(!fd || !buffer || buffer_len < 1)
        return -1;
    if(fd->pos > fd->dir_entry.file_size)
        return -1;

    uint16_t cluster_size = fd->fs->header.cluster_size;
    uint16_t cluster_num = fd->pos_cluster;///////////////////////////
    uint16_t buffer_left = buffer_len;
    uint16_t first_cluster_offset = fd->pos % cluster_size;

        //uint16_t cl = fat16_append_clusters(fd->fs, cluster_num, 1);
        //rprintf("A0 %d\r", cl);




    rprintf("N%d  OS%d \r", cluster_num, first_cluster_offset);



    //uint32_t pos = fd->pos;


    //rprintf("Csiz %d\r", cluster_size);
    //rprintf("Csiz %d\r", first_cluster_offset);
    //rprintf("BLeft %d\r", buffer_left);
    /* find cluster in which to start writing */
    if(!cluster_num)
    {
        cluster_num = fd->dir_entry.cluster;
        rprintf("C0 %d\r", cluster_num);
        if(!cluster_num)
        {
            rprintf("C1 %d\r", cluster_num);
            if(!fd->pos)
            {
            /* empty file */
                fd->dir_entry.cluster = cluster_num = fat16_append_clusters(fd->fs, cluster_num, 1);
                rprintf("C2 %d\r", cluster_num);
                if(!cluster_num){
                    return -1;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        if(fd->pos)
        {

            uint32_t pos = fd->pos;
            //rprintf("FDPOS %d\r", pos);
            uint16_t cluster_num_next;
            while(pos >= cluster_size)
            {
            //rprintf("FDPOS\r");
                pos -= cluster_size;
                cluster_num_next = fat16_get_next_cluster(fd->fs, cluster_num);
                if(!cluster_num_next && pos == 0)
    /* the file exactly ends on a cluster boundary, and we append to it */
                    cluster_num_next = fat16_append_clusters(fd->fs, cluster_num, 1);
                if(!cluster_num_next)
                    return -1;

                cluster_num = cluster_num_next;
            }
        }
    }

    /* write data */
    do
    {
        /* calculate data size to write to cluster */
        uint32_t cluster_offset = fd->fs->header.cluster_zero_offset +
        (uint32_t) (cluster_num - 2) * cluster_size + first_cluster_offset;
        uint16_t write_length = cluster_size - first_cluster_offset;
        if(write_length > buffer_left)
            write_length = buffer_left;

        /* write data which fits into the current cluster */
        if(!fd->fs->partition->device_write(cluster_offset, buffer, write_length))
            break;

        /* calculate new file position */
        buffer += write_length;
        buffer_left -= write_length;
        fd->pos += write_length;

        if(first_cluster_offset + write_length >= cluster_size)
        {
            rprintf("TEST %d  %d  %d\r", first_cluster_offset, write_length, cluster_size);
            /* we are on a cluster boundary, so get the next cluster */
            uint16_t cluster_num_next = fat16_get_next_cluster(fd->fs, cluster_num);
            if(!cluster_num_next && buffer_left > 0)
    /* we reached the last cluster, append a new one */
                cluster_num_next = fat16_append_clusters(fd->fs, cluster_num, 1);
                rprintf("NewCluster %d\r", cluster_num_next);
            if(!cluster_num_next)
            {
                rprintf("Zero\r");
                fd->pos_cluster = 0;
                break;
            }

            cluster_num = cluster_num_next;
            first_cluster_offset = 0;
        }

        fd->pos_cluster = cluster_num;

    }
    while(buffer_left > 0); /* check if we are done */

    /* update directory entry */
    if(fd->pos > fd->dir_entry.file_size)
    {
        //rprintf("UpdateFilesize\r");
        uint32_t size_old = fd->dir_entry.file_size;

        /* update file size */
        fd->dir_entry.file_size = fd->pos;
        /* write directory entry */
        if(!fat16_write_dir_entry(fd->fs, &fd->dir_entry))
        {
            /* We do not return an error here since we actually wrote
            * some data to disk. So we calculate the amount of data
            * we wrote to disk and which lies within the old file size.
            */
            buffer_left = fd->pos - size_old;
            fd->pos = size_old;
        }
    }

    return buffer_len - buffer_left;

#else
    return -1;
#endif
}
```

I'm totally stuck trying to figure out this maze....  any helps is appreciated.  If you need more code let me know.  I hope this is enough?

Comment: Does your platform have NULL-pointer dereference checks? If `malloc()` fails in `fat16_open_file()`, it'll return `0` to the caller, which doesn't do any NULL-pointer checks. Of course, `fat16_write_file()` does do a NULL-check on `fd`, so maybe it'll all work out alright in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about that library, and most likely you'll need debugger breakpoints and a lot of single stepping to figure out what's wrong, but I will say that I got [efsl (embedded filesystem library)](http://efsl.be/) 0.2.x -- the stable branch -- working ok on another small microcontroller.  So you might have more luck with that.

Comment: You mean you have an append function which continuously writes to the same file even after power up and power down?

Comment: Don't get me wrong the code runs and works but has that little flaw.... which is messing me up terribly.

Comment: @Tim: I know I've gotten open-for-append to work as well as open-after-powercycle (and open-after-hot-insert).  Can't remember for sure that I tested your exact use case, since mine is to create a new file and then concatenate them on the PC if necessary .

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the open function, it sets the file position to 0:

```
fd->pos = 0;
fd->pos_cluster = dir_entry->cluster;
```

In your open_file_in_dir_append function, you update the position, but use the same cluster as used for position 0:

```
result = fat16_open_file(fs, &file_entry);
result->pos = result->dir_entry.file_size;

result->dir_entry.cluster = result->pos_cluster; // <<-Help here
```

Looking at the [Documentation](http://www.roland-riegel.de/mega-eth/doc/group__fat16__file.html), there is also a fat16_seek_file function, you want to seek to the end of the file, so you should just call that function, I think it will look like this:

```
result = fat16_open_file(fs, &file_entry);
int32_t offset=result->dir_entry.file_size;
fat16_seek_file(result, &offset, FAT16_SEEK_SET);
```

You can also take a look at the code of fat16_seek_file what exactly is done there.